# How to extend powerBI token Id expiry time

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

How do I change the token Expiry time in power Bi?

Steps followed to generate token:

1. Registered [power Bi App](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps)
2. After providing the details got the `client id` and the `secret Id`
3. Using `client id` and `secret Id`, I generated the `token Id` on my `asp.net page`.
4. Using this `token Id`, I am able to access power bi report and bind into `iframe`.

It's working but after 1-hour `token Id` expires and I need to generate the `token Id` again by providing the power username and password which the user doesn't want to key in.

Comment: When and how are you generating the token? Are you using power bi embedded for non-power bi users or power bi embedded for power bi users (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding/)?

Comment: while loading the page , i am calling this url   with clinet iD and i am able to generate TokenId 
 but problem is that it's getting expiry after 1 hour. i have power Bi User but i am not passing . https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=5963172a-b292-460d-bc90-9dac5e33cea2&resource=https%%2f%2fanalysis.windows.net%2fpowerbi%2fapi&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a59220%2fRedirect.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `setAccessToken`  to update the access token without reloading the embedded report when the token is about to expire.
You can Refresh the token Manually or Automatically.

await report.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);

Manually Update token:
Set the newAcessToken Manually

```
let newAccessToken = await getNewUserAccessToken(reportId, groupId);
```

Automatically Update token:
Provide token generating function it will set an event hook in embed config parameters and call function which generates new token and reassign to generated expiring token

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/refresh-token